# Setting different margins for every certain pages?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a very large word file. In fact it has more than 500 pages. Now I want to set different left margins for every third page. Like page one, four, seven... have left margin 30
the rest have left margin 1. I try to do that by using vba like the following:

```
Sub SetMargin()
    Set MyDoc = ActiveDocument
    PageNum = MyDoc.Range.Information(wdNumberOfPagesInDocument)
    For i = PageNum To 2 Step -1
        Set Pos = MyDoc.GoTo(wdGoToPage, wdGoToAbsolute, i)
        Pos.insertBreak wdSectionBreakContinuous
    Next
    For Each i In MyDoc.Sections
        If (i.Index + 2) Mod 3 = 0 Then
            i.PageSetup.LeftMargin = 30
        End If
     Next
End Sub
```

But the problem is the article contains some long sentences, so after running the program, those sentences break into two lines and some pages just cannot contain the whole section and it floats to the next page. Thus some pages have two different left margins, which really confuses me since I am new at Word and VBA programming. There must be some way to fix that. But I don't know how. Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: First set the entire document to the widest margin setting you want to use. Then add your section breaks and narrower margins.

Comment: I tried several times, like reversing the conditions, but still get similar results @TimothyRylatt

Comment: Another approach is to set a _Different first page header/footer_ option, then add a text box with square or tight text wrapping to the the header to push the left margin over. Do an Internet search to get the details. Then in VBA. add a _Section Break (Next Page)_ before every page where you want a wide left margin.

Comment: Here are pages that discuss the option John mentions. http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/LetterheadRibbon.htm and http://addbalance.com/word/headersfooters.htm#2007-2013. The thing is that you do not want section breaks for this to the extent you can avoid them. It interferes with text flow, as you've noticed. The textbox or frame in the header gets rid of that.

Comment: The problem is that you are adding all the section breaks and then processing the sections to change the margins. Each time you change the margins the text is reflowed and the pagination changes. What you should be doing is adding the section break and changing the margin, if required, in the same operation.